# I have upload my app into play store, but some devices not appeared

Tags: android, build.gradle

below is used things in app

minSdkVersion 19,
targetSdkVersion 29

Below 8.0.0 version: Not visible in play store; 
8.0.0 version: Only this version phone can visible in play store; 
Above 8.0.0 version: Not visible in play store;

I have migrate to AndroidX

After rejection of app(due to app send SMS, and Call Permission) i have removed those options and again re-uploaded my app to play store

Now app is in live but, when i search app (Lifeonplus) is not displaying except 8.0.0 version phone. Please help me out this. where i went wrong? App should display above 4.4 version

Build gradle & class Path

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Model: App

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.digital.lifeonplus"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //Apache httpclient-android library
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'

    //Excluding httpclient since it is already part of httpclient-android
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: show your build.gradle and classpath

Comment: @Amiya, updated gradle & class path

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'` or 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer for my own question, i have used NFC hardware feature required true, so after that i changed it to false, its displaying all the phones

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false" />
```